# Using MC Data Extension to update HTML on Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

Is it possible to pass HTML code through a Data Extension value to set the HTML for an AmpScript Landing Page?

Comment: Please share more details, what you wish to achieve and what have you come up so far. So it would help the community to assist better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass HTML code through a Data Extension value to set the HTML for an AmpScript Landing Page. To do this, you can use the TreatAsContent() function in your AmpScript code on the landing page. This function will treat the specified string as content, allowing you to include HTML code in the string that will be rendered on the page.

Here is an example of how you might use the TreatAsContent() function to set the HTML for a landing page using a Data Extension value:

Copy code

```
%%[
/* Retrieve the HTML code from the Data Extension */
var @htmlCodeset @htmlCode = AttributeValue("HTML_Code_DE")
/* Set the HTML for the page using the TreatAsContent() function */
]%%

%%=TreatAsContent(@htmlCode)=%%
```

In this example, the TreatAsContent() function is used to treat the value of the HTML_Code_DE attribute as content, allowing the HTML code to be rendered on the page.

Keep in mind that when using the TreatAsContent() function, you need to make sure that the HTML code you are using is valid and well-formed. Any errors in the code could prevent it from being rendered correctly on the page. It's always a good idea to test your HTML code thoroughly before using it in your AmpScript landing page.